# Repeating argument transformation c#, better pattern?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating custom objects for a C# Unity game (Vector3 class is provided)

I have a series of functions on my object that I will be calling a lot, and I want a "high level" and "low level" version to cover convenience and performance.

Right now I am handling the code like this to try and avoid repetition

```
public uint getVal(Vector3 pos)
{
    return getVal((int)pos.x, (int)pos.y, (int)pos.z);
}

public uint getVal(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return data[getDataIndex(x, y, z)];
}

public void setVal(Vector3 pos, uint val)
{
    setVal((int)pos.x, (int)pos.y, (int)pos.z, val);
}

public void setVal(int x, int y, int z, uint val)
{
    data[getDataIndex(x, y, z)] = val;
}
```

However, while I am avoiding some repetition I am still repeating a more basic pattern which is:

Call Method With Vector3 + Addtl. Args -> Cast Vector3 and Call X, Y, Z Version of Method.

I am going to be a writing a lot more methods that follow this pattern, is there a better way to do this in C#?

Comment: Seems to me like your `getDataIndex` method needs to be the one that takes a vector3 or three ints. That way all of your getVal and setVal methods just pipe their input to `getDataIndex` which does the conversion.

Comment: will you be creating a lot of objects with this pattern, or do you have one object that will have lots of get/set methods like above?

Comment: One or two objects with lots of get / set methods.

Comment: Also, the getDataIndex does take a vector or multiple ints but it isn't much shorter to pipe directly to that sub function, and once I start adding methods that transform the input it won't be enough to pipe it later ...